# ngx-filter-pipe causing application to crash

Tags: angular, typescript, search

I'm using angular 7 for my project. I have a modal which shows users list and I have used [ngx-filter-pipe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-filter-pipe) library to search users from the list.
Now when I try to open the modal, it does not open and the whole application gets stuck.

I have searched through the git issues for this library but found nothing related to my issue.

Typescript:

```js
individualSearchFilter: any = {first_name:''}; //declaration of searchParam
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let student of studentsList | filterBy:individualSearchFilter">...</div>
```

When I remove the pipe everything works fine and modal opens but obviously search does not work.

Modal should open and search should work Properly as in the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-filter-pipe?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Hi, you indicate that the issue appears when you try to use it in a modal.  nowhere you put this code, also not in the stackblitz.   please put all the code for the error case and error if you have

Comment: when you open the model,check the studentsList is properly initialize . sometime when object is undefined modal crash , tips student array list name should be students or studentList , not studentsList :)

Comment: I do not see any modal in the `stackblitz` only the input field with `search Filter` ?

Comment: @ShahidIslam StudentsList is initialised. I've checked it properly. This is not the issue. Thank you for the correction, I'll change studentsList to students. :)